# PHPMyAdmin login error on RHEL 7 with MySQL 8 - mysqli_real_connect(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php-5.6, rhel7, mysql-8.0

I recently installed phpMyAdmin on RHEL with PHP 5.6.4 and MySQL 8 but but when I try to access it from the browser the following errors occur:

```
mysqli_real_connect(): Server sent charset (255) unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers
```

Can someone please let me know if you have come across similar error and any luck resolving it?

I have tried adding the below code on my.cnf file but that didn't help. Doing below worked for someone who was using PHP 7 but didn't work for me.

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
character-set-server = utf8
```

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Comment: Hello @Gaurav, where you able to solve this - am having a similar error and wondering if you resolved it?